# Is there a way to add a new column to a pandas multiindex that only aligns with one level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm looking for a clean way to add a column to a multiindex dataframe, where the value is only repeated once per level=0.

For example,

**I want to add a column to this:**

| Index level=0 | Index level=1 | Value (x) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 300 |
|  | 2 | 850 |
|  | 3 | 2000 |
| B | 1 | 100 |
|  | 2 | 70 |
|  | 3 | 400 |

**In order to get to this:**

| Index level=0 | Index level=1 | Value (x) | Value (y) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 300 | Yellow |
|  | 2 | 850 |  |
|  | 3 | 2000 |  |
| B | 1 | 100 | Red |
|  | 2 | 70 |  |
|  | 3 | 400 |  |

**I do *NOT* want this:**

| Index level=0 | Index level=1 | Value (x) | Value (y) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 300 | Yellow |
|  | 2 | 850 | Yellow |
|  | 3 | 2000 | Yellow |
| B | 1 | 100 | Red |
|  | 2 | 70 | Red |
|  | 3 | 400 | Red |

I'm not sure how best to create a table here that shows what I'm hoping for, but the important part to me is that y corresponds to all rows of index level=0, but is not repeated for every increment of index level=1.  I'm sure that I could the additional rows in the y column with null values but I thought there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: How do you determine `High` and `Low` ?

Comment: The values here in these tables are irrelevant, I'll change them to colors to avoid confusion. I'm only concerned about how to attach the new column, not its calculation.

Comment: I assume you can just do `df['Value (y)'] = ['Yellow',  'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, 1], 'Color'] = ['Yellow', 'Red']
print(df)

# Output
     Value   Color
A 1    300  Yellow
  2    850     NaN
  3   2000     NaN
B 1    100     Red
  2     70     NaN
  3    400     NaN
```

Or only with `slice`:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), 1), 'Color'] = ['Yellow', 'Red']
print(df)

# Output
     Value   Color
A 1    300  Yellow
  2    850     NaN
  3   2000     NaN
B 1    100     Red
  2     70     NaN
  3    400     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you High / Low are determined so I'm hard coding them in a dictionary:

```py
# Create the data frame
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1,2,3]])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [300, 850, 2000, 100, 70, 400]
}, index=index)

# The transformation
def f(col):
    y_values = {
        'A': 'High',
        'B': 'Low'
    }
    level0 = col.index[0][0]
    return [y_values[level0]] + [''] * (len(col) - 1)

df['y'] = df.groupby(level=0).transform(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate thru the index0 and assign value to new column for every new type of data in index0:

```
c=0
for i in df.index:
    if i[0] != c:
        #put your code here to add values to new column
        c = i[0]
```